# High CPU being caused by garbage collection in w3wp.exe

Tags: cpu-usage, .net, iis-8.5, memory-leak, garbage-collecting

I am having a problem with High CPU happening on my my website in IIS8.  This happens randomly and not very often but it does happen especially when the load is heavy on the site.  The only way to stop it is to End Task on the w3wp.exe process and it's fine.

I tried to to do a debug diagnosis below but I cant seem to figure out what exactly it means or how to read it since it doesnt provider much info.  Is there something else I should do to verify what the actually problem area is?

```
In w3wp.exe__example.com__PID__4944__Date__04_25_2016__Time_10_28_23AM__521__PERFTRIGGER_RULE1.dmp GC is running in this process. The Thread that triggered the GC is 338

When a GC is running the .NET objects are not in a valid state and the reported analysis may be inaccurate. Also, the thread that triggered the Garbage collection may or may not be a problematic thread. Too many garbage collections in a process are bad for the performance of the application. Too many GC's in a process may indicate a memory pressure or symptoms of fragmenation. Review the blog ASP.NET Case Study: High CPU in GC - Large objects and high allocation rates for more details
```

**Thread 338**

```
Entry point   0x00000000 
Create time   4/25/2016 10:26:26 AM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:02.750 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 

This thread is incomplete and also has/have an invalid Thread Environment Block pointer. As a result, the information reported is most likely inaccurate.

.NET Call Stack

Function 
System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef) 

Full Call Stack

Function   Source 
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+c    
KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+99    
clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+31    
clr!CLREventWaitHelper+2a    
clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+152    
clr!SVR::gc_heap::wait_for_gc_done+66    
clr!SVR::GCHeap::GarbageCollectGeneration+1c2    
clr!SVR::gc_heap::try_allocate_more_space+149    
clr!SVR::gc_heap::allocate_more_space+35    
clr!SVR::GCHeap::Alloc+8f    
clr!Alloc+54    
clr!AllocateObject+94    
clr!JIT_New+6b    
System_Core_ni+1e7a90    
System_Core_ni+1e7a61    
System_Core_ni+1db6ad    
System_Core_ni+1eb05a    
System_Core_ni+1e808b    
System_Core_ni+1ec3b0    
System_Core_ni+1eb20e    
System_Core_ni+1db6ad    
System_Core_ni+1eb05a    
System_Core_ni+1e808b    
System_Core_ni+1ec3b0    
System_Core_ni+1eb20e    
System_Core_ni+1db6ad    
System_Core_ni+1eb05a    
0x203fec01    
0x2272d822    
System_Web_ni+1dead7    
System_Web_ni+80a2df    
System_Web_ni+809f42    
System_Web_ni+809eee    
System_Web_ni+8095ad    
0x229a7c6c    
0x229a7948    
0x1aebccaf    
0x229a0c2e    
0x229a0a9a    
0x2298d7a3    
0x229a0131    
0x229a0afb    
0x229a18f8    
0x229a219e    
0x2298d7ab    
0x22988cb9    
0x22982eb4    
0x2298222c    
0x22981fce    
0x22981d69    
0x22981e50    
0x22981e50    
0x22981e50    
0x22981c25    
0x227caa8e    
0x227cab65    
System_Web_ni+b40d76    
System_Web_ni+1e2e15
```

Comment: use WPR/WPA to diag CPU usage. Capture a trace  with WPR (http://stackoverflow.com/a/36733523) (also select .net activity under scenario) and analyze it with WPA (https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis) and expand the stack of w3wp.exe. if it is really GC, analyze the ETL also with Perfview for GC issues: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-125-PerfView-Part-8

Comment: have you tried WPR/WPA?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you make too much garbage, so the GC takes too much time to collect it. Happens when you have bad programming.

So, grab a memory profiler and analyze where the garbage comes from. Then fix the crapping code.

Comment: Is there anyway to figure that out from the production environment?  It could be anything if I tested on my local machine.

Comment: Not without installing debugger tools. Which is not so hard if you put in a VM behind a load balancer to have a debuggable produciton machine for exactly this reason. Alternatively start putting up a performance test environment.

Comment: @exposure use WPR, here you can capture it in production, transfer the generated file + NGEN PDBs to your dev system and analyze it there